# this.Setstate is not working correctly in reactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to the react.

I have this state :

```
     state = {
    isLoading: true,
  };
```

And I have this lifecycle function

```
 componentDidMount() {
    const { setPageCount, receiveApiData } = this.props.actions;
    const { isLoading } = this.state;
    const getData = () => {
      this.setState({ isLoading: !isLoading });
      receiveApiData();
      setPageCount();
    };
    setInterval(() => {
      getData();
    }, 30000);
  }
```

Here is what I'm trying to return in render():

```
 return isLoading ? (
  <Loading></Loading>
) : ( `Some Code here`)
```

The problem is state is Always true and my lifecycle method is not changing it to the false so my app can not render the false condition.
I don't know what to do,any suggestions please?

Everything else in `getData()` is working correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
this.setState({ isLoading: !isLoading });
```

because `isLoading` what you are destructuring taking previous value i.e it is not taking latest state value so its not updating your `isLoading`  . What you need to do is this:

```
this.setState({ isLoading: !this.state.isLoading });
```

Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-chandrasekhar-pluv7?file=/src/App.js:312-332

Answer (score 1):

Since your new state depends on the value of your old state, you should use the functional form of `setState`

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  isLoading: !prevState.isLoading
}));
```

Official documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous